# Setting profile pic from an upload OR an external URL using Paperclip

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, paperclip

I would like to let my users set their profile picture by either:

- Providing a remote URL into a text box that I will use to grab the image into an S3 bucket
- Uploading a file using SimpleForm's `file_field` method

I would love to know the cleanest way to allow users to do both of these from the same form. I have done some experimenting but not come up with anything particularly satisfactory yet. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The following is a good guide giving a general idea how to do an upload via a url. Its very old but it gives a good general idea of what needs to be done.

http://trevorturk.com/2008/12/11/easy-upload-via-url-with-paperclip/

After doing something like the above, first I would start with both the url and upload field disabled. Then I would just have some javascript, and a buttons that upon selecting url or upload un disabled the corresponding field by removing attribute disabled.